# Django admin panel shows empty list on foreignkey dropdown menu

Tags: django

I do have record in my DB, but there is only a search box in the dropdown menu:

[errorimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEiM8.png)

When I type in something that is actually not there, it will show "No result found"

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GmPI.png)

A js error occurred when I click on the dropdown:

> select2.min.js:2  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Code - `admin.py`:

```py
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ModelA

admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
```

`Model.py`:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=15, null=False)
    link = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I've searched for a few hours but I don't find anyone have the same issue as me. What should I do to solve this?